# iOS / iPad site reloads on scroll, not when using anchor

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, ipad

I'm working on fixing this site: 
http://soulsoundformations.nl/

It's hosted on a LAMP server and it uses CMSMS 2.1x in case this matters.
(And yes, all the smarty stuff is slowing it down.)

On desktop it works fine, but on iPad when I scroll by swiping, it reloads.
If I swipe part way and hold I can just about see much of the content is also not rendered.

I tried the translate3D trick and changing position: fixed to absolute, but that didn't change anything, and it broke the layout.

Anyone any idea where I should look to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: PS: If I use the anchors, it goes to the spot fine and it renders fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that website reloads when you resize screen, so try to delete

```
this.location.reload(true);
```

from line 120 at `http://soulsoundformations.nl/js/mo-en-mo-functions-v1-2.js`

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Weird that it fired on iPad without an actual resize... But that will teach me to leave code from previous versions in... Thanks!!!